# Prerendering vs. loadtime optimization

Tags: performance, page-speed, load-time, google-pagespeed, server-side-rendering

While loadtime optimization we turn many adjusting screws, which all have different efficiency and need different afforts.

**Is it not better to prerender** all, or most important, pages and to guarantee, that Google and our visitors get a blazingly loading plane HTML document?

Prerendering can be bought as service, or implemented on own server. Anyway, this will be a single action we need - instead of many optimization steps, different stackeholders, different dependencies we have, if we optimize every single loadtime facet.

Prerendering is already brightly used for aking crawlable Javascript-based sites. What argues against prerendering of PHP/MySQL sites ?

Comment: Sites built with PHP and may mysql usually serve HTML already without any JavaScript. What do you suggesting pre-rendering would do for such sites?

Comment: You are right, indeed. But prerendering creates a plain HTML page, which will be delivered to both of Google and visitors. DB queries, PHP and js execution are away. I even optimized on this way an outdated CMS page from about 40 to more then 90 PSI points - only with prerendering and with 15 minutes of time affort. I mean, why all struggle with TTFB, LCP TTI and other particular stuff, if a prerendered page is a plain HTML, which loads ways faster as an PHP/MySQL/JS/CSS/WOFF... page?

Comment: I can see how you could create an HTML cache to eliminate database calls, but how would you get rid of JS, CSS, and WOFF?    Prerendering a Anguar site doesn't usually get rid of any of those.  It just creates the initial HTML server side rather than client side.

Answer (score 1):

"It depends" - On the functionality of the site and the tradeoffs one is willing to make. Pre-rendering is indeed very useful for static, high volume pages or static pages where cpu is very constrained - but you give up an awful lot to get there, including a lot of user interactivity and harder maintenance.

Computers are unbelievably fast (and some software - like Wordpress with lots if plugins stupidly bloated). The problem here is not dynamic content, its trying to be all things to all people. Of-course many of these frameworks have plugins ehich effectively pre-render pages on denand using caching.

Writing lightweight dynamic content can be almost indistinguishably aa fast as static content - and in these circumstances other factors like latency, bandwidth, disk IO, memory [caching[ can be larger concern then CPU.

Of-course, static files can often cache better and can be easier to secure.

Prerendering can speed up complex sites, but in the simplest cases  MySQL is a database and a filesystem is a database - but MySQL will allow me to index multiple keys, making searches faster on things other then a filename index.

If its speed over everything, you dont need per-user customisations and you can ignore the savings of a general solution over developer time costs - yes, pre-rendering is better. Those are big ifs.